# There is an error adding a custom LibreOffice extension

Tags: python, libreoffice-calc

Good afternoon.

I wrote an extension for LibreOffice. Here is its structure:

[image]

The contents of the file **datalink.py**:

```
import uno
import unohelper
from com.sun.star.task import XJobExecutor
from pythonpath.services.messageboxservice import MessageBoxService

class DataLink(unohelper.Base, XJobExecutor):
   implementationName = "vnd.datalink"                                     
   serviceNames = ("com.sun.star.task.Job",)                               

   def __init__(self, context):
      self.context = context

   def trigger(self, args):                                               
      MessageBoxService("Hello World!!! Args: " + args, "Info")

g_ImplementationHelper = unohelper.ImplementationHelper()

g_ImplementationHelper.addImplementation(DataLink, DataLink.implementationName, DataLink.serviceNames,)
```

The contents of the file **messageboxservice.py**:

```
import uno

from com.sun.star.awt.MessageBoxType import INFOBOX
from com.sun.star.awt.MessageBoxButtons import BUTTONS_OK

class MessageBoxService:

   @staticmethod
   def Show(text, caption, type = INFOBOX):
      context = uno.getComponentContext()
      sManager = context.ServiceManager
      toolkit = sManager.createInstance("com.sun.star.awt.Toolkit")
      msgbox = toolkit.createMessageBox(None, type, BUTTONS_OK, caption, text)
      return msgbox.execute()
```

The contents of the file **manifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest:manifest xmlns:manifest="http://openoffice.org/2001/manifest">
     <manifest:file-entry manifest:full-path="Addons.xcu" manifest:media-type="application/vnd.sun.star.configuration-data"/>
     <manifest:file-entry manifest:full-path="datalink.py" manifest:media-type="application/vnd.sun.star.uno-component;type=Python"/>
</manifest:manifest>
```

When you add a **DataLink.oxt** extension file to LibreOffice, the following error occurs:
[image]

**Question**: How did I correct this error?

**P.S.** may need to make any changes to the above files

Comment: Well-formatted question with all necessary details. One suggestion for improvement: Post the text of the error message, rather than requiring us to read it from the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything inside the `pythonpath` directory is included in the path, not the directory itself. So, the import statement should be:

```
from services.messageboxservice import MessageBoxService
```

For reference, see https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python#Importing_Modules, although it doesn't give a clear example that answers your question.